# PHP, PDO fetchAll how to unserialize specific row

Tags: php, pdo

As title, i use php PDO connection how to unserialize `row['node_relation']` row when i use `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Here's the data in DB:

```
arrow_sn | x1 | x2 | y1 | y2 | node_relation
830      | 365| 334| 545| 389| s:11:"1-A-1,2-A-2";
```

Here's the code:

```
$nodesData = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM map_node");
    $nodesData->execute();
    $row = $nodesData -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($row);
```

Comment: Do you want to `unserialize()` the row OR column? Also, how many rows are you returning? 1 or many? If just 1, you could do `$row[0]['node_relation'] = unserialize($row[0]['node_relation']);` before doing the `json_encode()`;

Comment: @Sean Thanks for your answer. i only want to `unserialize()` column which column name is node_relation are saved `serialize()` data. And it should be many not only 1. Sorry for not clearly.

Comment: You could either do a `foreach()` on the `$row` and do the `unserialize()`, or you could change the `fetchAll()` to `fetch()` in a loop where you would `unserialze()` the column before adding it to the `$row` array.